# Error 424 Object required on End Sub

Tags: vba, excel

Long time lurker, first time poster.  This error has been bugging me for weeks, so I have had to resort to asking for help.

I have an excel add in that I have developed.  The add in has a custom right click menu, which replaces the standard excel right click menu uning SheetBeforeRightClick.  This works perfectly fine, execpt when you delete the row that you have right clicked on.

For example.  You right click on the cell E11 on the "Major Projects" sheet to bring up the menu.
Menu code:

```
Private Sub SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ClstrCmd As CommandBar
'Display cluster display option commands
On Error GoTo connerr
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Control" Then
            Cancel = True
            Set ClstrCmd = FinanceCreateSubMenuControlNew
            ClstrCmd.ShowPopup
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Input" Then
            Cancel = True
            Set ClstrCmd = FinanceCreateSubMenuInputNew
            ClstrCmd.ShowPopup
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Major Projects" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Projects GP Report" Then
            Cancel = True
            Set ClstrCmd = FinanceCreateSubMenuProjectsNew
            ClstrCmd.ShowPopup
    Else
        'No Menu for this sheet
    End If
connerr:
End Sub

Function FinanceCreateSubMenuProjectsNew() As CommandBar

''Create some objects
Dim cb As CommandBar
Dim cbc As CommandBarControl

''Ensure our popup menu does not exist
FinanceDeleteCommandBar "FINANCE_PROJECTS"

''Add our popup menu to the CommandBars collection
Set cb = CommandBars.Add(Name:="FINANCE_PROJECTS", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=False)

Set cbc = cb.Controls.Add
With cbc
    .Caption = "Insert Seperator Row"
    .OnAction = "InsertMajorProjectsSeperator"
End With
   Set cbc = cb.Controls.Add
With cbc
    .Caption = "Delete Seperator Row"
    .OnAction = "DeleteMajorProjectsSeperator"
End With

Set FinanceCreateSubMenuProjectsNew = cb

End Function
```

You select "Delete Row" from my custom menu.  This calls the Procedure Deleterow.

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Deleterow = ActiveCell.Row

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Major Projects").Range("A" & Deleterow) = "x" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Major Projects").Rows(Deleterow).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "You haven't selected a seperator to delete"
    End If
End Sub
```

That deletes the selected row.  Once the row has been deleted the code drops back to the FinanceCreateSubMenuProjectsNew function.  Then to the SheetBeforeRightClick procedure to finish.  It gets to End Sub on the SheetBeforeRightClick procedure and gives a 424 - Object requred error.  There is no debug option, and I can't error trap it as it appears to error after the End Sub.  I can only assume its because the cell that you have right clicked on has been deleted and the system has lost the Target.  If I put in a
    msgbox Target.address
I can cause the error to occure at that line.  If I 
    set Target = activecell
before the msgbox that fixes that error, but it still errors on End Sub.  Is there a System Target type of variable I need to reset?

Even putting in a 
   sheet("Major Projects").Range("a1").select 
doesn't help.

Becuase the code errors, the Addin unloads.  So then the user needs to restart the addin before they can use any of the functionality again.

The real kicker is, once I hav restarted the addin I can delete rows without getting the error.  The only way to get the error again is to completely close Excel and start again.  Closing the file only doesn't cause the error to reoccure.

Comment: If your intention is to replace the right-click menu entirely then try placing `Cancel = True` at the bottom of your event so that it is always cancelled. I haven't looked in detail (it's late) but I would hazard a guess that your event is being called twice in succession.

Comment: Also disable your error handling - you need to see the error(s). It is a v.bad idea anyway to have a handler that doesn't handle the error.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I do handle errors correctly in my live code, but just stripped it down for this site (or it would be 1000's of lines long).  Disabling the error handleing does nothing as the error occurs on (after?) the End Sub.  So all code is completed by then.  Its Like excel has a SystemTarget Variable that is set to the cell you have clicked on.  If you delete the cell it looses the value and errors.  But works fine there after.  Its a Bizzare one.  I have added the extra cancel = true.  But it didn't stop the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something simple and it didn't compile (a variable name same as the Sub name). May be you should define and use a Long type variable `lngDeleteRow`:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim lngDeleteRow as Long

    Debug.Print "ActiveWorkbook: " & ActiveCell.Worksheet.Parent.Name
    Debug.Print "ActiveSheet: " & ActiveCell.Worksheet.Name
    Debug.Print "ActiveCell: " & ActiveCell.Address
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "DeleteRow() : ERR " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    lngDeleteRow = ActiveCell.Row

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Major Projects").Range("A" & lngDeleteRow) = "x" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Major Projects").Rows(lngDeleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "You haven't selected a seperator to delete"
    End If
End Sub
```

You may also want to put more Debug.Print lines throughout your live code to pin point the error. When I have situations like this, I would add `Debug.Print Now & vbTab & "Sub/Function name - Start"` at each beginning Sub and function, and a "Finish" at the end so I can trace error more accurately in the Immediate window.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Thats a good pickup, but it hasn't solved the fault.  Even if I just say ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Major Projects").Range(A1:R500).EntireRow.Delete to clear existing data before re running a query and thats happens to be the range I have clicked on to instigate the menu, it errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer ended up being using an Application.OnTime function to call the delete function. This allows the delete to happen separate to the rest of the code running.